# Reverse result of a partition from a list using Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller, datalistitem

Lets say I have three tables(*Person_tbl*, *PersonHobbies_tbl* and *Hobbies_tbl*) with relationships between them like:

```
Person_tbl [1]-------[n] PersonHobbies_tbl [n]-------[1] Hobbies_tbl
```

The logic is that a specific person can have more hobbies. I want to retrieve a list of hobbies which are not assigned to a specific person represented by it`s ID.

For example if I want to get a list of hobbies which is assigned to a specific person, I can do this like:

```
DBEntity db = new DBEntity();

var Person = db.Person_tbl.Find(id); //id contains the ID of a person
var obj = Person.PersonHobbies_tbl;

//lets say that ViewListResult cointains only HobbyName
return obj.Select(n => new ViewListResult   
{
    HobbyName= n.Hobbies_tbl.name
}).ToList();
```

I want to obtain the opposite of this(a list with the rest of the hobbies) in a efficient way.

So my question is how can I solve my problem in a efficient enough way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick linqpad test that should get you what you need.

```
void Main()
{
    var hobbies = new List<Hobby>()
    {
        new Hobby { ID = 1, Name = "Test 1" },
        new Hobby { ID = 2, Name = "Test 2" },
        new Hobby { ID = 3, Name = "Test 3" },
        new Hobby { ID = 4, Name = "Test 4" }
    };

    var ids = new[] { 2, 3 };

    var rest = hobbies.Where(x => !ids.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
    rest.Dump();
}

public class Hobby
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


ID  Name
1   Test 1 
4   Test 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Except` to exclude the hobbies of a person from all hobbies:

```
var obj = db.Hobbies_tbl.Except(Person.PersonHobbies_tbl);
```

I think using `Except` has better performance than `Contains` because there is some internal HashSet used to implement the excepting operation.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution, but your code is not good becouse `Hobbies_tbl` and `PersonHobbies_tbl` are not the same type. If I will be able to collect all the hobbies related to one person then use this within `Except` it would solve my problem.

Comment: @DaniFeldman I did not know they are of different types. But it's strange about your design. I thought all hobbies of a person should be contained inside hobbies table? After being imported to your model, they should have the same type.

Comment: @DaniFeldman so `Person.PersonHobbies_tbl` are not all the hobbies related to person? it's confusing here. So does the `Person` have any navigation property to its hobbies? I believe it should have if you imported  your model correctly.

Comment: It is just an example for my real problem. I have more tables which are connected together with a table(`PersonHobbies_tbl` ) that contains the ids of the connected tables. So `PersonHobbies_tbl` contain ids(id for hobby too) and `Hobbies_tbl` contain datas related to hobby(for example `name`).

Comment: @DaniFeldman so how did you actually get related hobbies of a person? (I thought you simply needed this `Person.PersonHobbies_tbl`). Of course if you know that you can just pass it in `Except` as in my answer. Currently I have no much info about person to help you on that.